# Problems with long tables

Tags: tables, supertabular

I want to print a long table in LaTeX, i.e. it has to break across pages. I'm getting so many line breaks in the table. My code and sample table is attached. Code is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular, booktabs}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{diagbox} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document}
        \begin{strip}
        \centering
        %\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \tablefirsthead{%
            \toprule
            Layer / Operation & Input Shape1 / Output Shape1 & Input Shape2 / Output Shape2 & Layer Type & Kernel Size & No.of Kernels &  Strides & Stride Size &  Padding & Activations &  Calculation & No.of Parameters\\ \midrule \\
        }
        \tablehead{%
            %\hline\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\small\sl continued from previous page}\\
                    Layer / Operation & Input Shape1 / Output Shape1 & Input Shape2 / Output Shape2 & Layer Type & Kernel Size & No.of Kernels &  Strides & Stride Size &  Padding & Activations &  Calculation & No.of Parameters\\ \midrule \\
        }
        \tabletail{%
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{5}{c}{\small continued on next page} \\
            \bottomrule \\
        }
        \tablelasttail{%
            \bottomrule \\
        }
        \tablecaption{Publication Distribution with the Design Space}
        \label{tab: designSpace} 
        \begin{supertabular}{@{}|p{\dimexpr 0.06\textwidth-\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.10\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.07\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.10\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}|p{\dimexpr 0.12\textwidth-2\tabcolsep \relax}
                |p{\dimexpr
        0.08\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax              }|@{}}
            %\begin{supertabular*}{p{0.20\textwidth}p{0.22\textwidth}p{0.20\textwidth}p{0.18\textwidth}p{ 0.20\textwidth}}
            Input      & (256 x 256 x 1)   & (128 x 128 x 1)   & Input   & - & - & - & - & - & - & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0} \\   
        \hline
        Conv1\_1 & (256 x 256 x 64) & (128 x 128 x 64) & Conv2D &  (3, 3)   & 64 & 1 & - & 'same'   & ReLU & (9 * 1 + 1) * 64 & 640 \\      
        \end{supertabular}
    \end{strip}     
\end{document}
```

Sample image is

[image]

Comment: Don't mix-and-mismatch vertical rules and the macros of the `booktabs` package.

Comment: i'm a new user in latex.can you help me to correct this

Comment: Are you ok with getting rid of all vertical rules?

Comment: The column widths sum to more than 100% of `\textwidth`, and you haven't accounted for the fact that the vertical rules themselves occupy some space as well. And, does your document use two-column mode? Please confirm.

Comment: article is two column but table is one column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147851/discussion-between-user-and-mico).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest switching to one-column mode *before* starting the `supertabular` material. You also need to assure that the sum of the column widths doesn't exceed `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{afterpage} % for '\afterpage' macro
\usepackage{supertabular, booktabs, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\relax}}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{%
\clearpage % flush any accumulated floats
\onecolumn % switch to one-column mode

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt

\tablefirsthead{%
  \toprule
  Layer\slash Opera\-tion & Input shape1\slash Output shape1 & Input shape2\slash Output shape2 & Layer type & Kernel size & No.of kernels &  Strides & Stride size &  Pad\-ding & Activations &  Calculation & No.\ of parameters\\ 
  \midrule 
  }
  
\tablehead{%
  %\multicolumn{12}{@{}l}{\small\slshape continued from previous page}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
  Layer\slash Opera\-tion & Input shape1\slash Output shape1 & Input shape2\slash Output shape2 & Layer type & Kernel size & No.of kernels &  Strides & Stride size &  Pad\-ding & Activations &  Calculation & No.of parameters\\ 
  \midrule 
  }
  
\tabletail{%
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{12}{r@{}}{\small continued on next page} \\
  }
  
\tablelasttail{%
  \bottomrule 
  }
        
\tablecaption{Publication distribution with the design space}
  \label{tab: designSpace} 
        
\begin{supertabular}{@{}
        P{0.09\textwidth-1\tabcolsep}
        P{0.10\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.10\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.07\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.07\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.07\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.09\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.08\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}
        P{0.08\textwidth-1\tabcolsep} @{}}

Input    & (256 $\times$ 256 $\times$ 1) & (128 $\times$ 128 $\times$ 1) & Input & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & -- & 0 & 0 \\   
\midrule
Conv1\_1 & (256 $\times$ 256 $\times$ 64) & (128 $\times$ 128 $\times$ 64) & Conv2D &  (3, 3)   & 64 & 1 & -- & `same'   & ReLU & (9 $\times$ 1 + 1) $\times$ 64 & 640 \\      

\end{supertabular}

\twocolumn% back to two-column mode
}% end of scope of '\afterpage' directive

\end{document}
```

Comment: how to center the contents of each cell \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\hspace{0pt}}p{\dimexpr #1\relax}} is not working

Comment: @user - I suggest you replace `\RaggedRight` with either `\Centering` or `\centering\arraybackslash` in the definition of the `P` column type. I prefer `\Centering`, as it'll allow hyphenation of long words.

Comment: I need vertical and horizontal center

Comment: @user - To get vertical centering, change `p{\dimexpr` to `m{\dimexpr` in the definition of the `P` column type.

Comment: @user -- What is `.topline`, and what is `.midline`? Are you maybe trying to refer to `\toprule` and `\midrule`? Incidentally, I think it would be a good idea to replace the interior `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` directives. By "interior", I mean the ones in the body of the `supertabular` enrironment.

Comment: @user - Please edit your own posting, not mine.

Comment: @user - Please read what I write carefully. I certainly did *not* state you should replace `p{\dimexpr...` with `p{m{\dimexpr}`. Instead, I wrote you should use `m{\dimexpr`. I stand by this. And I suggested in a different comment that you replace the `\midrule` directives in the body of the `supertabular` environment; did you follow up on this suggestion?